# How to set the List Height when List is empty?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I got my data from API and put them in a list. My problem is that is it possible to set fixed height when the array in the list were all deleted? I use  environment(.defaultMinListRowHeight, 80) but it didn't work.Please help. Thank you

```
func containedView() -> AnyView {
    switch self.selectedIndex {
   case 0:
       return AnyView(
        List(userNotifications1.userNotificationsArray) { userNotification in
        UserNotificationCellView(userNotification: userNotification,userNotifications: self.userNotifications1)
        }.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 80)
.environment(\.defaultMinListHeaderHeight, 10)

        )

   case 1:

      return AnyView(           
        List {
            ForEach(managerNotifications, id: \.id) { (managernotification) in
                ManagerNotificationCellView(managerNotification : managernotification)

            }.onDelete(perform: self.deleteManagerNotification)
        }
    )

   default:
    return AnyView(Text("22").padding(40))
    }
```

[when list has data, the cell's height are bigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NHtg.png)
[when list is empty,the cell's height was small](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBuCa.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set environment variable in correct place. Below tested as **works with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2**.

[image]

```
List {
  // ... list content here
}
.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 80) // << should be for List
```

Comment: hey bro, thanks for your comment. I fixed this issue by putting Spacer() in my List. This can make my List column height fixed when empty. Thank you.